# How can I use the dribbble api for each person thats logs in?

Tags: ajax, laravel, api, httprequest, guzzle

This is how I get my dribbble account. but I want that each user can connect their dribbble account to display their images and not mine

```
<script>
// Set the Access Token
var accessToken = "df8d770e9d19b6e0839c429244f60282e80375b34fded2792907cbb581c8022b"

// Call Dribble v2 API
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.dribbble.com/v2/user/shots?access_token='+accessToken,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {  
      if (data.length > 0) { 
        $.each(data.reverse(), function(i, v`enter code here`al) {                
          $('#dribbbleShots').prepend(
            '<li class="shot" target="_blank" href="'+ val.html_url +'" title="' + val.title + '"><div class="title">' + val.title + '</div><img src="'+ val.images.hidpi +'"/></li>'
            )
        })
      }
      else {
        $('#dribbbleShots').append('<p>Sorry, No shots yet</p>');
      }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: for what i can see in the api, they gives you only tools to manage the current user registered.... i think that a possible way is using some web crawler on "https://dribbble.com/username" to get it...

Comment: the documentation on dribble for the user is very limited... I really don't understand what I need to do....